# error installing gd librarry for mapserver

Tags: linux, bash, gd, rhel5, mapserver

I am installing all external and required libraries before compiling and installing source code of mapserver-6.4.1

I have installed all libraries successfully except **libgd**.

I have downloaded libgd from [here](https://github.com/libgd/libgd/archive/gd-2.1.1.tar.gz)

I am following the below procedure to compile gd library. But i am getting error on this.

```
[root@localhost /]# cd /usr/local/src/libgd-master

[root@localhost libgd-master]# ./configure

[root@localhost libgd-master]# -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Comment: try `bash configure ` if it won't work then post the output of `ls` command.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing `./configure`
run

```
automake
```

After which the file `configure` will be generated.

Comment: Is automake a file on source code directory or it is a tool or other library? i searched in gdlib source code directory, i not found any file like automake

Comment: `automake` is a tool/command. That will parse `configure.ac` file to generate `configure` script

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install the system rpm for libgd?

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/15161687/dir/redhat_el_6/com/libgd2-2.0.33-2_11.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

Or you may want the el7 package.

You can install automake as part of the autotools package.